# Database most efficient tables system

Tags: mysql, django, database

I'm using Django and Mysql in order to, for instance, display some news articles. These articles are in English and German. I would like to know what database organization is more efficient:

1 table made of the following fields:

**Articles**

- English_title  (char field)
- English_body  (char field)
- German_title  (char field)
- German_body  (char field)
- Picture  (file field)

*or*

2 tables made of the following fields:

**English articles**

- English_title  (char field)
- English_body  (char field)
- Picture       (file field)

**German articles**

- German_title (char field)
- German_body  (char field)

It'll display English articles on a template and German ones in another one.

Comment: Imagine you having more languages, and localization team for each language...

Comment: @metatoaster it does! I'd take the 5th method of the second answer. What do you think about the performance? Is this method the best one in this aspect?

Comment: You will have to benchmark this yourself for your specific use case, but in general left-joins are a fairly standard operation in many RDBMS engines, so provided that your indexes are set up correctly, the additional performance cost should be fairly negligible for a single left-join.